# Get selected Item from the list with JS

Tags: javascript

I have an html  list with some items loaded. I am able to get the select list object using the following code:

```
var list = document.getElementById('ddlReason');
```

but I need help with figuring out how to detect which value has been chosen from the list.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Gets your select
var list = document.getElementById('ddlReason');

// Get the index of selected item, first item 0, second item 1 etc ...
var INDEX = list.selectedIndex;

// Viola you're done
alert(list[INDEX].value);
```

Edit (forgot .value).

You can also make that a bit more concise, but I wanted to make it readable so you could see what was going on. Shorter version:

```
var list = document.getElementById('ddlReason');
alert(list[list.selectedIndex].value);
```

Comment: Pretty sure that should be list.options[INDEX].value

Comment: In all browsers? I may be about to learn something.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can do this

```
var list = document.getElementById('ddlReason').value;
```

and if you make an alert to `list`, you'll get the value of your select tag.

Answer (score 2):

The list object will have a 'options' attribute that is an array of all the options in the list and a 'selectedIndex' attribute that contains the index of the selected item (or the first selected item if there are multiple). So you can do this:

```
var list = document.getElementById('ddlReason');
var selectedValue = list.options[list.selectedIndex];
```